# Keypad not hiding in fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I am facing an issue with fragment. I have a fragment with a listview when I tap an Item in listview another fragment is opened which contains an edit text, and when I tap in the edittext keypad is opened. There is an ok button and when I tap the ok button 
 the previous fragment is shown. But the key pad remains there. I need to hide the keypad. But if I didn't opened the keyboard by tapping thee edit text in the second fragment, it is working fine. When the second fragment is opened and if I tap the save button without entering the text the keyboard is not displayed.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Did you try my solution? Is it what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

To hide keyboard use:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
     getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

if (imm.isAcceptingText())                   
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 
        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```